# Making sticky javascript

Tags: javascript, sticky

I have a javascript form where I am using innerHTML to set some text.

When the form submits that information is lost.Is there anyway I can make it "sticky".I was thinking a cookie but that's about all I know.

Thanks

```
<form "action="" name="myform">
<input type="text" name='name">
<div id="theName"></div>
</form>
```

Quick example I am capturing the name and need the div to show the name after the form submits.

Comment: Could you provide an example? Sounds like you need something server-side.  Javascript is only client side, so the client browser would have to run this function every time.

Comment: Hi it is really a very simple form and it needs to be all javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to persist the data somehow. There are several options:

- Store it on the server. When the form is submitted, your server-side script will receive the data; it can persist it in a database, session variable, or some other form of storage that's appropriate for your application. Whenever the client re-visits the page with the form, have the server generate the form's HTML with the persisted data.
- Use HTML5's [local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). While not supported in legacy browsers, all modern ones provide the local storage API. When the user submits the form (attach an event listener to the form's "submit" event), you can store the form data by making calls to `localStorage[key] = value` and retrieving it with `localStorage[key]`.
- Store it in a cookie. Although I don't recommend this approach, you can create a cookie with the form data. The only restriction is that the data needs to be represented as a string, but I recommend [JSON](http://www.json.org/). However, you probably should not use this approach since cookies are sent to the server for each request; if the form fields contain a lot of data, then you're also unnecessarily sending a lot of data to the server.

Using HTML5's local storage gives you a self-encapsulated approach that requires no server-side configuration:

```
<form action="" name="myform">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <div id="theName"></div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var form = document.getElementsByName('myform')[0];
    if (localStorage['name'] !== undefined) {
      var displayArea = document.getElementById('theName');
      displayArea.textContent = localStorage['name'];
    }
    form.addEventListener('submit', function() {
      var nameField = document.getElementsByName('name')[0];
      localStorage['name'] = nameField.value;
    }, false);
  })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you setting the "value" attribute of the input tags to something or blank? you can just remove (remove the attribute itself) that so that the last value set will be used (true only for non-password type inputs. also, haven't tried it in all browsers.).

Or better yet, you can use serverside script like (PHP, ASP, RUBY, etc) to set the attribute value to the previously submitted.

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="txtinput" id="txtinput" value="<?php echo $_POST['txtinput']?>"/>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

doing it in js only is much more complicated and unreliable since your going to use cookies.

PS: I'm assuming your not using XHR(AJAX) to submit your forms since XHR's don't refresh pages or re-initializes inputs unless you told them to.

Answer (score 0):

This should be happening server-side. Javascript is for enhancing a page, it's not to be depended on for data manipulation.

Your script, converted to PHP, would look like

```
<form action="" method="post" name="myform">
  <input type="text" name='name">
  <div id="theName"><?php
    if(isset($_POST['name'])) { echo $_POST['name']; }
  ?></div>
</form>
```

...and it would work every time, without having to call any JS.

You'll have to handle the form data somehow anyway - how were you intending to retrieve the data without a server-side script?